# Macbook Pro 2018 Touch Bar Gone dark and not working

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, touch-bar

I have a 15" 2018 Macbook Pro with touchbar and the touchbar has gone completely black! the only thing working is the touch id. Also, there are no touch bar related settings in the keyboard settings section.

I've seen his problems for the last couple of days, after the machine unexpectedly shut down, and then it showed "your computer restarted because of a problem"

I've tried:

1. ```
   pkill "Touch Bar agent"; 
   killall "ControlStrip";
   ```

   and

   ```
   sudo pkill "Touch Bar agent"; sudo killall "ControlStrip";
   ```
2. Starting in Safe Mode
3. SMC reset NVRAM
4. reset Apple Hardware Test (booting while holding D),
       resulting in "No problems found"
5. re-installaing MacOS
6. updating to Catalina.
7. Pressing fn to see whether that would light the touch bar up (it didn't work)

Has anyone encountered this issue as well?

Comment: I ended up doing a factory reset, then it started working.

Comment: Please share what worked for you as an answer, with enough detail so that someone else can repeat what you did. For example, "factory reset" is not necessarily clear to many people.